# Taking the address of a function and discarding it at compile time: is this valid C++?

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I was looking for a way to restrict template type parameters to those implementing functions of given signature. I seem to have arrived at quite elegant solution that allows for self-documenting code and rather clean, Concept-like error messages. The only problem is that I'm not sure if that's valid C++ or something that just happens to work in clang and gcc.

Here's the code:

```
#include <type_traits>
using std::enable_if;

// let's say we want something with a "regular" operator+

class Thing
{
public:
    Thing operator+(const Thing&){return Thing();} //the kind of operator we want
};

class OtherThing
{
public:
    OtherThing operator+(int){return OtherThing();} // the kind of operator we don't want
};

class YetAnotherThing
{
    // no operator whatsoever
};

// The questionable line. I'm taking the address of the function and 
// immediately discarding it using the comma operator.
#define HAS_FUNCTION(type, ret, name, args...) (static_cast<ret (type::*)(args)>(&type::name), 1)

#define T_HAS_OPERATOR_PLUS HAS_FUNCTION(T, T, operator+, const T&)

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<T_HAS_OPERATOR_PLUS>::type foo(T)
{
    T t1, t2;
    t1 + t2;
}

#undef T_HAS_OPERATOR_PLUS

int main()
{
    Thing t;
    OtherThing ot;
    YetAnotherThing yat;
    foo(t);
    foo(ot);
    foo(yat);
}
```

When build with clang it produces the following output:

```
main.cpp:43:2: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
        foo(ot);
        ^~~
main.cpp:29:47: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = OtherThing]: static_cast from 'OtherThing (OtherThing::*)(int)' to 'OtherThing (OtherThing::*)(const OtherThing &)' is not allowed
typename enable_if<T_HAS_OPERATOR_PLUS>::type foo(T)
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~        ^
main.cpp:44:2: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
        foo(yat);
        ^~~
main.cpp:29:47: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = YetAnotherThing]: no member named 'operator+' in 'YetAnotherThing'
typename enable_if<T_HAS_OPERATOR_PLUS>::type foo(T)
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~        ^
2 errors generated.
```

...which looks pretty nice compared to the usual arcane blizzard.

So, my question is: is it valid in standard C++14? After all I am taking an address at compile time, it seems like something that would be disallowed by the standard.

Also, since I'm but a mere apprentice of the dark arts, perhaps there's a more straightforward way to accomplish this?

Either way any input is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, boost TypeTraits has an implementation of this that you can use without having to roll you own - see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_plus.html). Second, you generally only want to use `enable_if` when there are multiple potential overloads and you want to remove some from the candidate set. If you simply want to enforce that `T` satisfies some concept, it's much cleaner to just use a `static_assert`. For instance:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(T)
{
    static_assert(boost::has_plus<T, T>::value, "T must support operator+");
    // Impl...
}
```

Comment: The error message for a SFINAE'd away function can be much easier to understand than that of an exploded function body. Unfortunately, failing the `static_assert`ion doesn't abort analysis of the remaining function body.

Comment: What if I want a function that is not an operator? Can boost take care of this?